# New install help

Tags: system-installation

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64 Bit on my computer with windows vista and after I sign in all I get is a purple screen? After looking online and trying installing nvidia driver still not working. I now see where my computer is 32 bit so I downloaded a new 14.03 32 Bit version but when I try to install this version it wants to install along side of Windows and the not working Ubuntu 64 Bit version. Can I replace the 64 Bit version with the 32 Bit. The end result I'm looking for is just to replace the 64 Bit with the 32 Bit and hopefully that will fix my problem.

EDIT: My Specs are

```
Windows Vista 32 bit <-- Not needed
Intel core (TM) 2 CPU, 4400 @ 2.00 GHZ
2GB RAM
Nvidia GeForce 7500LE
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I now see where my computer is 32 bit "?

Comment: It is an older computer the specs are: Windows Vista 32 bit, Intel core (TM) 2 CPU, 4400 @ 2.00 GHZ, 2GB Ram, Nvidia GeForce 7500LE.

Comment: You can replace an already installed Ubuntu. There should be a radio button for that that says `Replace an existing Ubuntu` or something similar.

Comment: This is a 64-Bit CPU, so no need to reinstall to 32-Bit

Comment: No option to replace existing Ubuntu.my options are 1-replace everything, 2- Add alongside Windows and Ubuntu 64 Bit version, 3- something else.

Comment: How do you know it's a 64 Bit CPU

Comment: For one your 64 bit Ubuntu installed and it would not on a 32 bit processor and I think that all Inte Core(2) (duo, i3,i5,i7) processors are 64 bit.

Comment: And a short Google search and the official intel page said so :-D

Comment: Just checked computer and it is X86 based PC so a 32 Bit

Comment: Kev I never got your comment

Comment: Anyway is there a way I can replace the existing Ubuntu without adding a 3rd

Comment: Yes it is x86 **based** but 64-Bit CPU also know as amd64 or x86_64. That only means that all the x86 (32-Bit) instruction set is working on that as well.

Comment: There are hundreds of tutorials out there please use a search-engine with `ubuntu manual installation`. At google the first entry looks very promising and should cover all cases, even yours

Comment: Here's what I did after I install Ubuntu 14.04 and got the purple screen. 1st- apt-get purge nvidia-*, apt-add-repository ppa:Cory-edgers/ppa 2nd- apt-get update && apt-get dist.upgrade 3rd- aptitude search nvidia 4th-apt-get install nvidia-304* nvidia- settings. Rebooted and  after a long time the desktop does load but is frozen. I can't do anything. This is when I thought I should try the 32 Bit version or maybe I should try an older version. That is why I would like to replace the excisting Ubuntu without adding another version alongside this non working version

Comment: Sorry xorg not Cory.

Comment: I've searched the Internet and couldn't find the solution

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice and clean [Install NVIDIA GeForce driver](http://www.howopensource.com/2012/10/install-nvidia-geforce-driver-in-ubuntu-12-10-12-04-using-ppa/). To enter these command press `ctrl+F1` to switch to a non graphical interface. Type in you username and your password and enter the given commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current nvidia-settings
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Hi Kev, its better to at least paraphrase the linked to document and include all the steps incase it is removed at a later date.

Comment: Yes you are right. I added the commands and paraphrase the link. Thank you +1 for that

Comment: Give me a minute I'm going to try that Nvidia update again

Comment: I tried the Nvidia install but no luck. Still boots to the frozen desktop

Comment: I would like to give the 32 Bit version a try if I knew how to replace the excisting 64 Bit version without effecting Windows

Comment: Then if that doesn't work I'll try an older version

Comment: Still waiting to see someone can help me. Thanks